# Python: how to base64 encoding of a formatted text file and get the same formatting after deconding

Tags: python, text, encoding, base64, decoding

I have a text file with this kind of content:

```
__META__
Autore             myname@mycompany.com
Data               2011/09/29_11:37:00
Sorgente           Non applicabile
Layout             1.0.0
Copyright          MyCompany
Note               Standard_Build
__INFO__
Nome               PACKAGE-NAME
CodiceProduzione   PKG_CODE
Descrizione        Descriptiom
ChangeOwner        organizational.unit@mycompany.com
Vendor             sigla=IC nome=MyCompany-SD
__SOURCE__
#Server             oldserver.mycompany.com
Server             newserver.mycompany.com
__CONTENTS__
_dir_              dir=/opt/package/x uid=user gid=group mode=755 policy=nn
#_dir_              dir=/tmp  uid=user gid=group mode=755 policy=nn
_file_             file=/opt/package/x/file1 uid=user gid=group mode=600 policy=nn
_file_             file=/opt/package/x/file2 uid=user gid=group mode=755 policy=fv
_file_             file=/opt/package/x/file3 uid=user gid=group mode=755 policy=fv
__SCRIPT__
postinstall        scr=/opt/package/x/file1.sh 
__END__
```

Then I open the file and encode the content into base64, like so:

```
import base64

MetaFile = '/path/file.tx'

data = open(MetaFile, "r").read()
data_byte = data.encode("utf-8")
MetaFile_encode = base64.b64encode(data_byte)

MetaFile_decode = base64.b64decode(MetaFile_encode)

print(MetaFile_encode)
print(MetaFile_decode)
```

The `print(MetaFile_encode)` line shows the base64 encoded file content:

```
b'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'
```

But when I decode into base64 "MetaFile_encode" I no longer get an output formatted like the original, and instead of a new line I get the character "\n", like so:

```
b'__META__\nAutore             myname@mycompany.com\nData               2011/09/29_11:37:00\nSorgente           Non applicabile\nLayout             1.0.0\nCopyright          MyCompany\nNote               Standard_Build\n__INFO__\nNome               PACKAGE-NAME\nCodiceProduzione   PKG_CODE\nDescrizione        Descriptiom\nChangeOwner        organizational.unit@mycompany.com\nVendor             sigla=IC nome=MyCompany-SD\n__SOURCE__\n#Server             oldserver.mycompany.com\nServer             newserver.mycompany.com\n__CONTENTS__\n_dir_              dir=/opt/package/x uid=user gid=group mode=755 policy=nn\n#_dir_              dir=/tmp  uid=user gid=group mode=755 policy=nn\n_file_             file=/opt/package/x/file1 uid=user gid=group mode=600 policy=nn\n_file_             file=/opt/package/x/file2 uid=user gid=group mode=755 policy=fv\n_file_             file=/opt/package/x/file3 uid=user gid=group mode=755 policy=fv\n__SCRIPT__\npostinstall        scr=/opt/package/x/file1.sh \n__END__\n\n'
```

What should I do to get a decoded text formatted as the starting one?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Think carefully about the steps that were taken in the code. First we converted the `str` to `bytes` by using the UTF-8 encoding; then we converted those `bytes` to a different `bytes` using base64. So, to reverse that, we need to use base64 backwards to turn the `bytes` into the UTF-8 encoded `bytes`, which is what we see in the question... and then what? I'm voting to close this as a typo, because the problem is a matter of simple reasoning and apparently not due to a lack of knowledge.

Comment: Put another way: what happens if you try `print(data_byte)` immediately after calculating it? What would you do to get the original `data` back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You base64 encoded the already UTF-8 encoded string. The base64 decode returned that UTF-8 encoded string. You see it as a `bytes` object starting with `b'` and escaping non-printing characters such as `\n`. The solution is just one more step: Decode the UTF-8 bytes into a string.

```
import base64

MetaFile = '/path/file.tx'

data = open(MetaFile, "r").read()
data_byte = data.encode("utf-8")
MetaFile_encode = base64.b64encode(data_byte)

MetaFile_decode = base64.b64decode(MetaFile_encode)
data_decode = MetaFile_decode.decode("utf-8")

print(MetaFile_encode)
print(MetaFile_decode)
print(data_decode)
```